# Assembly in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm having one assembly.I need to use that assembly in my application.i dont want to give reference to that assembly and not GAC also.

How to use that assembly in my application?

Comment: The title of this question must be improved.

Answer (score 3):

Make use of reflection and load assembly dynamically tha you can call the methods of it.

here is one example of it

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("MyNice.dll");

Type type = assembly.GetType("MyType");

object instanceOfMyType = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

[Dynamically Loading an assembly at Runtime and calling its methods](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/sridhar_subra/dynamicassemblymethod10132008214835pm/dynamicassemblymethod.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use reflection

You can refer to this link for more details as to possible implementation

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/csharpreflection.aspx